# SoftLayer Invalid login credentials provided

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried SL account and my IBMid to login Softlayer portal (http://control.softlayer.com/), both work fine.
But when I tried these account with SLcli (softlayer-python), it returns "Invalid login credentials provided".

Do anyone met this issue?

```
steve@k8s-1:~$ slcli -v config setup
Username [xxxxx]:
API Key or Password [xxxxxx]:

..............

Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.softlayer.com
https://api.softlayer.com:443 "POST /xmlrpc/v3.1//SoftLayer_User_Customer HTTP/1.1" 200 236
=== RESPONSE ===
{'Content-Length': '236', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Connection': 'close', 'ntCoent-Length': '420', 'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Date': 'Thu, 24 Nov 2016 06:07:03 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

.......

SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_User_Customer_LoginFailed): Invalid login credentials provided.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the Python client, I reported the issue:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/783

As a workaround you can use, in the Python client, the username and APIKey displayed in the control portal for that:

1. log on to the control portal
2. Click on Account-> Users menu
3. Click on the IBMid or username
4. See API access information (Note the information will be displayed once your APIKey has been generated)

[image]

Let me know if you are still having issue with this.

Regards

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstand the API key.

Comment: The Python client should work with both your username and apikey or your username and password (the one you use for control), but it has been broken when the IBMid accounts were added to softlayer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the password or API Key is correct, then you should verify that you're using the correct username. In other words, go to Control portal, navigate to the Users list and click on the **View** link that's under the **API Key** column. There should be the correct username and API key information.

[image]

Comment: I misunderstand the API key. It's not the user account password. And Only master account can see this API key.